# websites report in ansible: how to register_var per host or set_facts per host?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create simple report:

```
- name: collect info about servers
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: template list
      template:
        src="servers_report.j2"
        dest="~/ansible/reports/webservers_report.csv"
      connection: local
```

with simple csv-template:

```
hostname;provider;
{% for item in play_hosts %}
{{ item }};{{ hostvars[item].provider }};
{% endfor %}
```

Works fine. Then i need to add colums with websites list (folders list in `/www`), something like this:

```
- name: folder list
  shell: "find /www -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f,'"
  register: folderlist
- name: debug list
  debug: "msg={{ folderlist.stdout }}"
```

(sample output is:

```
TASK [debug list] **************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "www,site1.com,site2.org,"
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "msg": "www,site3.co.uk,site123.com,"
}
```

, `folderlist.stdout` contains comma-separated site's list for inserting into report)

How can I place this variable into my template file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set_fact` assigns host fact that can be accessed via `hostvars` later on.

```
- name: folder list
  shell: "find /www -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f,'"
  register: folderlist
- name: assign fact
  set_fact:
    www_list: "{{ folderlist.stdout }}"
```

And in your template:

```
{{ item }};{{ hostvars[item].provider }};{{ hostvars[item].www_list }};
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!